# Remove merge without losing local commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have two branches called "task1" and "task2". Now I'm working in branch "task1".

I did a `git merge task2` and it works properly. Now I'd like to write some code in "task1" and after that I want to remove that merge without losing changes that I just did.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

So, you would like to keep the *content* of the current branch task1 but only showing 1 single revision after its starting point (starting point of your explanation, that is)? If that is the case:

```
git checkout task1
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m "Merge and the last commit joined together, no merge will show up"
```

And you are done.

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked my question wrong. I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git revert` to undo all the changes introduced by the merge commit.

```
git log ## to get commit hash from merge
git revert <merge-commit-hash>
```

Find more detail on git revert [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert).

Answer (score 0):

Change to branch *task1*

```
git checkout task1
```

`merge` *task2* in *task1*. This will generate a commit who appoints the HEAD to a specific commit

```
git merge task2
```

Make some changes on *task1* and commit the changes

```
...
```

To find the commit-hash **before** merging the branches

```
git log
```

`reset` *task1* before `merging` task1 to *task2*. With `--soft` the file changes will stay in your working tree.

```
git reset --soft <commit_before_merge>
```

[Tutorial for undo a merge](https://www.datree.io/resources/git-undo-merge)